Emulator not working using android-commandlinetools installed through brew on MacOS (Cannot find valid SDK root path)
I've some troubles trying to run my android emulator and SDK,
First, it seems that the SDK is deprecated when I try to run:
brew install --cask android-sdk
I got this error:

android-sdk has been officially discontinued upstream.

Checking here I get this post
So I tried installing the command line tools:
brew install --cask android-commandlinetools

The output for this command is this:
 Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-mac-11076708_latest.zip
Already downloaded: /Users/testcomputer/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/76a8eee9e0f62a261183b58c78c572e87fbd8acad42af527407b2974526cb4de--commandlinetools-mac-11076708_latest.zip
==> Installing Cask android-commandlinetools
==> Moving Generic Artifact 'cmdline-tools' to '/usr/local/share/android-commandlinetools/cmdline-tools/latest'
==> Linking Binary 'avdmanager' to '/usr/local/bin/avdmanager'
==> Linking Binary 'lint' to '/usr/local/bin/lint'
==> Linking Binary 'retrace' to '/usr/local/bin/retrace'
==> Linking Binary 'sdkmanager' to '/usr/local/bin/sdkmanager'
==> Linking Binary 'apkanalyzer' to '/usr/local/bin/apkanalyzer'
==> Linking Binary 'screenshot2' to '/usr/local/bin/screenshot2'

I exported the variables in my zshrc file:
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/share/android-commandlinetools
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$PATH

I also installed the emulator:
sdkmanager "emulator"

After this I tried getting an android image:
sdkmanager "system-images;android-34;google_apis;x86_64"

This worked ok...
And create the avd:
avdmanager create avd -n myavd -k "system-images;android-34;google_apis;x86_64" --device "pixel_3"

So far so good, now I entered to my emulator path:
cd $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
ls //=> output cmdline-tools    emulator    licenses    platform-tools  system-images
cd emulator
ls //=> LICENSE         android-info.txt    emulator        lib64            
package.xml     resources
NOTICE.csv      bin64           emulator-check      mksdcard        qemu             
source.properties
NOTICE.txt      crashpad_handler    include         netsimd         qemu-img
_CodeSignature      crashreport     lib         nimble_bridge       qsn

Now I try to run my emulator:
./emulator -avd myavd

The error that I get is this:
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-testcomputer/emu-crash-35.1.20.db, detection is enabled for process: 68485
INFO    | Android emulator version 35.1.20.0 (build_id 12234392) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Graphics backend: gfxstream
INFO    | checking ANDROID_HOME for valid sdk root.
emulator: WARN: /Users/testcomputer/Library/Android/sdk is not a directory, and canot be sdk root
INFO    | checking ANDROID_SDK_ROOT for valid sdk root.
WARNING | platforms subdirectory is missing under /usr/local/share/android-commandlinetools, please install it
emulator: WARN: Cannot find valid sdk root from environment variable ANDROID_HOME nor ANDROID_SDK_ROOT,Try to infer from emulator's path
INFO    | guessed sdk root is /usr/local/share/android-commandlinetools
WARNING | platforms subdirectory is missing under /usr/local/share/android-commandlinetools, please install it
INFO    | guessed sdk root /usr/local/share/android-commandlinetools does not seem to be valid
INFO    | guessed sdk root is /usr/local/share
WARNING | platforms subdirectory is missing under /usr/local/share, please install it
INFO    | guessed sdk root /usr/local/share does not seem to be valid
INFO    | guessed sdk root is /usr/local
WARNING | platforms subdirectory is missing under /usr/local, please install it
INFO    | guessed sdk root /usr/local does not seem to be valid
WARNING | invalid sdk root /usr/local
emulator: WARN: Cannot find valid sdk root path.
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [/usr/local/share/android-commandlinetools]!

Do I need to install something else?... Not sure why this tries to access to SDK folder when using android-commandlinetools I don't have a SDK folder
Hope you can help me guys, I'm a newbie with android development. Thank you!

ChatGPT helped me here a lot, I've got missing platform directory
sdkmanager "platforms;android-XX" "platform-tools" "emulator" "system-images;android-XX;default;x86_64"
where XX is version of android
This install all essential components
